# Deployment error in jboss 6 for EJB 2.1

Tags: jboss6.x

We are trying migrate from jboss 4.2 to jboos 6.0.
I have deployed an ear file in jboss 6, which is build in netbeans 5.0, i'm using EJB 2.1 version in neatbeans. when i deploy the file, its showing the following exception,
kindly help me to sort out this problem.

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/muruganantham/My%20Documents/
Downloads/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/agencyconfiguration.ear" is in
 error due to the following reason(s): org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-complex-typ
e.2.4.b: The content of element 'web' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun
.com/xml/ns/j2ee":context-root}' is expected. @ vfs:///C:/Documents%20and%20Sett
ings/muruganantham/My%20Documents/Downloads/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/dep
loy/agencyconfiguration.ear/META-INF/application.xml[10,11]

```
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(Dep
```

loyersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(Dep
loyersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainD
eployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.c
heckComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$Delegate
Deployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.
deploy(HDScanner.java:246) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.
complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(Two
PCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificat
ionAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificat
ionAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(Modif
icationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internal
Perfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performW
rite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(
AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(
AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanne
r.java:146) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner
.java:90) [:0.2.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:44
1) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java
:317) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.
6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908) [:1.6.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_21]

Answer (score 0):

Just overcame a similar issue.  JBoss 5 and 6 are much more strict with DTD validation than earlier versions, especially the 4.x series.  Your `jboss.xml` file is failing DTD validation, either because element order is incorrect, or there are elements which don't validate against the DTD.

Take a look at the order of the XML elements in `standardjboss.xml`, and you'll see how your `jboss.xml` file differs.